# Android Java open activity after email sent

Tags: java, android, email, android-activity, send

Im trying to start a new activity AFTER the email is sent
I use the following to invoke the default email client

```
this.startActivity(Intent
.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

This works fine and starts the email app when you send the message it reurns you to the activity it starts from

I want to then start a new activity( the main Screen) and then close the previous one

I inserted the following

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity1.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
finish();
```

This works but the email screen is hidden behind the new activity and i have to quit the app to send the email

is there a way of starting the activity after the email is sent?

Im using gmail as the client

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find any info that when you start email client with `starActivityForResult()` it returns with some result code whether user send email or cancel that action. Gmail sent activity is started within your activity stack so you end up starting two activities, gmail app as second.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "tony@mail.com"});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"sent a message using for testing ");

    email.setType("message/rfc822");

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client:"),
                        1);
```

You need onActivityResult method like below

> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
>   resultCode, Intent data) {
>
> ```
> if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
>     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>
>
>     } else {
>
>         Intent ingoHome = new Intent(current.this,
>                 newclass.class);
>
>         startActivity(ingoHome);
>
>
>     }
> }
>
> finish();
> ```
>
> }